# Ignore/supress Warning during Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

A certain task generates a ##[warning] and has a warning status.
It causes the final status of stage to be an orange exclamation mark.
I want to suppress this so that the stage will show as succeeded (green check).
Is there a way to achieve this?

Ive looked at the options at the task itself, but it only has ContinueOnError

*Edit:
Im talking about the Azure App Configuration Extension.
[image]

I've even delved into the path of updating the Build Result via [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#buildresult)
but to unfortunaly, the PATH method doesn't seem to update the build result.

Comment: which task it is? what it the exact warning?

Comment: Did you check the Continue On Error option in your build definition setting? Could you also provide build result screenshot here. Which may make question more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update from OP**

It's a known limitation/bug of task:

[Azure DevOps Extension: Azure AppConfiguration - Partial Complete](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues/372)

---

Currently, by default the build result is "Failed" if anything failed to compile/build, "Partially Succeeded" if there are any unit test failures,ContinueOnError checked, and "Succeeded" otherwise.

`It causes the final status of stage to be an orange exclamation mark.`

According to your description, that task showing as "Partially succeeded" may due to you checked "Continue on error" option.

> **Continue on error (partially successful)**
> Select this option if you want subsequent tasks in the same job to
> possibly run even if this task fails. The build or deployment will be
> no better than partially successful. Whether subsequent tasks run
> depends on the Run this task setting.

Please refer to this document for more info: [Task control options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#task-control-options)

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying, I think the task I was talking about has a bug:
https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues/372

Comment: Hi michiel, thanks for your info. According to the link, it's more related to task itself. We could not do much in pipeline side and suppress that warning. We may have to wait and track the issue status.  Besides, you could also move your comment to reply and *mark your reply as an answer*, which will also help others in the community.