# Azureml SDK v2 The provided asset name will not be used for anonymous registration

Tags: azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I am trying to create an environment using AzureML SDK v2 and it throws Warning/Error as follows:

```
##[error]Warning: the provided asset name 'my_environment_name' will not be used for anonymous registration
```

This breaks my Azure Devops Pipeline, and also I do not understand the meaning of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:
[Register your model and environment separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-online-endpoints?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=azure-cli#register-your-model-and-environment-separately)

---

I assume you followed the [how to create component pipeline v2 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-component-pipeline-python?view=azureml-api-2) and created a `mldesigner.command_component` by specifying the `environment` parameter with a `dict` object or an [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-ml/azure.ai.ml.entities.environment?view=azure-python) object.

E.g.:

```py
import mldesigner

environment=dict(
    name="my_env",
    conda_file="conda.yaml",
    image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04",
)

@mldesigner.command_component(
    name="prep_data",
    version="1",
    display_name="Prep Data",
    description="Convert data to CSV file, and split to training and test data",
    environment=environment,
)
def prepare_data_component(
    input_data: Input(type="uri_folder"),
    training_data: Output(type="uri_folder"),
    test_data: Output(type="uri_folder"),
):
    pass
```

If you run above Python snippet in a script you will receive a warning:

```
Warning: the provided asset name 'my_env' will not be used for anonymous registration
```

This means, although you specify the name it is not used since a pipeline command job has an anonymous environment.
In the [Azure ML Environment Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-environments?view=azureml-api-2) we find:
*"Anonymous" environments are automatically registered in your workspace when you submit an experiment. They will not be listed but may be retrieved by version.*

More precisely an environment `CliV2AnonymousEnvironment` will be created with a GUID.

Using above component in an Azure ML pipeline won't result in an error, though. Of course your Azure DevOps pipeline will fail based on this warning.

**Solutions**

1. [Register your model and environment separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-online-endpoints?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=azure-cli#register-your-model-and-environment-separately)

The advised solution would be to manage your environment separately of your pipeline. So create an environment via the SDK ([Manage Environments V2 Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-environments-v2?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli)) and specify it in your command component:

```py
environment="azureml:my_env@latest"
```

2. Name your environment `CliV2AnonymousEnvironment`

If you would like to keep using an anonymous environment provided via the dictionary object rename it to `CliV2AnonymousEnvironment`. Using this name won't raise the error from above.

3. Configure your Azure DevOps pipeline not to fail on this warning

E.g. ([Ignore/supress Warning during Azure Devops Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286891/ignore-supress-warning-during-azure-devops-pipeline))

---

I hope this helps, looking forward to feedback. I also do not find it obvious how all the components are linked in Azure ML.